# extract specific rows from multiple files

Tags: shell

I have multiple text files and I want to extract the 4th and 5th row of each of the text files and output it to a new file. For example:

I have the text files:

```
tfa.txt
tfb.txt
tfc.txt
...
```

Where tfa.txt contains:

```
line1a
line2a
line3a
line4a
line5a
line6a
```

Where tfb.txt contains:

```
line1b
line2b
line3b
line4b
line5b
line6b
```

etc..

I want the following output:

```
line4a
line5a
*newline*
line4b
line5b
*newline*
line4c
line5c
...
```

and so on for all of the .txt files.

Comment: So, you have a **task**. But what a **specific problem** you ask us about? How to iterate files? How to extract a line with given index from the file? How to print newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk's `NR` and `FNR` special variables are really handy for such tasks. E.g.:

```
awk 'FNR==1&&NR!=FNR{print ""} FNR==4||FNR==5' tf*.txt
```